# Implementing two generic IEnumerable interfaces with different type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Having code as below, getting a compile error - "... does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'".

How to implement the non-generic version of GetEnumerator?

```
public class Giraffe { }
public class Pigeon { }
public class Sample : IEnumerable<Giraffe>, IEnumerable<Pigeon>
{
    IEnumerator<Giraffe> IEnumerable<Giraffe>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
    IEnumerator<Pigeon> IEnumerable<Pigeon>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not going to be particularly helpful, because the compiler will never be able to tell which IEnumerable you'd like your guy to be treated as.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I read an article, and I'm curious that how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class Pets :IEnumerable, IEnumerable<Giraffe>, IEnumerable<Pigeon>
        {
            IEnumerator<Giraffe> IEnumerable<Giraffe>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return null;
            }
            IEnumerator<Pigeon> IEnumerable<Pigeon>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return null;
            }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: IEnumerator actually requires generic type. I had tried your way, but I got another error.

Comment: Add `using System.Collection` to your using list. Its not defined in the `System.Collection.Generics` namespace.

Comment: You should throw a `NotSupportedException` in this case (since by design the method will not be implemented).

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem correctly, here is a sample how you can implement non-generic Enumerator in your class

```
public class Sample : IEnumerable<Giraffe>, IEnumerable<Pigeon>
{
    IEnumerator<Giraffe> IEnumerable<Giraffe>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
    IEnumerator<Pigeon> IEnumerable<Pigeon>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null; //your logic for the enumerator
    }
}
```

since the generic `IEnumerable<T>` inherits non-generic `IEnumerable` so implementing `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` would define an implementation for the same.

you may additionally declare the class as `public class Sample : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<Giraffe>, IEnumerable<Pigeon>` for more clarity

example

```
public class Sample : IEnumerable, IEnumerable<Giraffe>, IEnumerable<Pigeon>
{
    IEnumerator<Giraffe> IEnumerable<Giraffe>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
    IEnumerator<Pigeon> IEnumerable<Pigeon>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null; //your logic for the enumerator
    }
}
```